# Java program to reverse words read from txt file

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program in Java so I can read a file, reverse every single word, meaning if the sentence is "Hello Java" the output should be "olleH avaJ".I have been able to do the reverse but with the program I have written the output is "olleHavaJ" with  no space. Can someone help me fix it? Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;

public class ReadWords {
 public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException {

 File f=new File("words.txt");
 Scanner input=new Scanner(f);
 String result="";
 while(input.hasNextLine()) {
     String fjala=input.next();
     for(int i=fjala.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
         result+=fjala.charAt(i);
     }

 }
 input.close();
 System.out.print(result+" ");
   }
 }
```

Comment: After *for* loop add a space `result+= " "`

Comment: Please, edit and show the output

Comment: Does it work after the edit?

Comment: Yes it does work

Comment: Any idea how can I reverse the entire file? Meaning if the file is "Hello Java,my name is X" the output should be "X si eman ym,avaJ olleH".This is just an example cause the file would be long and I can't do it with input.nextLine()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do not edit your question to add the solution. Leave it like it was so other users will understand your initial problem, and suggest more answers. Other users meant to edit your code, not your SO question. @user7 should post the answer and you should mark it as solved if it worked.

Comment: Ok I will put it back as it was and user7 can post the answet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my initial comment as an answer.

You can add a space once you have constructed the reversed word.

```
for(int i=fjala.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
   result+=fjala.charAt(i);
}
result += " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nextLine()` instead of `next( )` (though this can be solved using next also) method, and do `split(" ")` and assign it in `String[ ]` as follows.

```
String[ ] words = in.nextLine( ).trim( ).split(" ");
```

Now apply reverse function on each word and push it in the output file.

Hope this solves your problem :)